# Cannot open USB device with libusb-1.0 in cygwin

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, libusb-1.0

I'm trying to interface with a USB peripheral using `libusb-1.0` in cygwin.

`libusb_get_device_list(...)` works fine, I get a list of USB devices. It finds the device with the correct VendorID and ProductID in the device list, but when `libusb_open(...)` is called with that device, it always fails with the error code `LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND`.

I don't think it's a permission issue, I've tried running this as admin, and there's a separate error code (`LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS`) for that. This same code works with `libusb-1.0` in Linux.

```
unsigned init_usb(int vendor_id, int product_id, int interface_num)
{
  int ret = libusb_init(NULL);
  if (ret < 0) return CONTROL_ERROR;

  libusb_device **devs = NULL;
  int num_dev = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devs);

  libusb_device *dev = NULL;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_dev; i++) {
    struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
    libusb_get_device_descriptor(devs[i], &desc);

    if (desc.idVendor == vendor_id && desc.idProduct == product_id) {
      dev = devs[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  if (dev == NULL) return CONTROL_ERROR;

  libusb_device_handle *devh = NULL;
  ret = libusb_open(dev, &devh);

  //ret is always -5 here (in cygwin)!
  if (ret < 0) return CONTROL_ERROR;

  libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);

  return CONTROL_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was a kind of driver issue. I had to tell Windows to associate the particular device I'm using with the libusb drivers.

[libusb-win32-1.2.6.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/libusb-win32-releases/1.2.6.0/) comes with some tools to make that association (although you may need to configure your system to allow the installation of unsigned drivers).

There's one tricky bit. If you just want to associate the device with libusb, you can use the `inf-wizard.exe` tool to make that association, but that will change the primary association to be with libusb. In my case, the device is a USB Audio Class device (i.e. USB sound card) that *also* has some libusb functionality. When I used `inf-wizard.exe`, libusb started working (yay!), but then it stopped working as an audio device.

In my case, I needed to use the `install-filter-win.exe` tool to install a filter driver for libusb. That allows the device to still show up as a USB Audio device, but also interact with it using libusb.